# An alien lands on earth and hides in a tree

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book in paperback form in the 80s.

So, this thing, with an incredible name (eg. XVASRASNMN) - would be very difficult to pronounce - is part of a swarm - Definitely part of some kind of insectoid race, I remember that much - but only one is here on earth and I think the story begins with this thing up a tree, invisible to us, analysing its surroundings... basically, it then pounces on someone who passes by and they are now under the controlling influence of the alien...

As time goes by, it captures more and more people and this network of people gradually become more powerful in terms of doing the alien's bidding... in the end, there is a massive battle - with the military partly compromised by the alien's influence too...

But if memory serves me right, its responses become slower and slower due to the massive network of human minds it now occupies, and I think each and every command it issues, has to travel through the ENTIRE network of people under its influence (I think it gets defeated due to finally taking too long to respond!!)

I'd really like to have a copy of this book but I'm damned if I can remember the title...

Could anyone possibly help/anyone recall anything like it?